# Is there a way to create a dialog in material design lite?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, material-design-lite

I have created dialogs using Angular Material, but so far haven't found a way to create one using Material Design Lite. Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 4):

MDL has support for styling HTML5 dialogs but does not include any polyfills for them. So you must have a browser that supports them (like Chromium). Else use a polyfill like https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill as pointed out by @manuel-84

```
<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Hello User</h4>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <p>Hello world from dialog!<p>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Disagree</button>
    </div>
</dialog>
```

And using a button somewhere call

```
document.getElementById('dialog').showModal();
```

See [Material Design Lite Components : Dialogs](http://getmdl.io/components/index.html#dialog-section)

Comment: or just use a polifyll like https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a user of MDL, not an insider.  But, as I understand it, Dialog support isn't there, but it's being worked on.  Tagged for V1.1, but no idea what the schedule for that might be.

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/pull/1762

Answer (score 0):

Not a dialog per se, but what I am doing in one project is to have a form slide down, using jQuery you get some nice animation

Basically define the form in a card, set the height to zero and opacity to 0. Then execute the following script to reveal the dialog

```
           $('#objects_card_holder').animate({
                    height: 400
                },500,function(){

                    $('#objects_card_holder').animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    },100,function(){
                        $('#projectName').val('');
                    });
            });
```

Then when the form is not required run another script to hide it.

```
        $('#objects_card_holder').animate({
            opacity:0
        },
        100,
        function(){
            $('#objects_card_holder').animate({
                height:0
            },
            500,
            function(){
            });
        });
```

Assuming that your card has the id objects_card_holder

Of course if you really need a dialog jQuery has it's own dialog.
see https://jqueryui.com/dialog/